# Is there a performance difference between using ARRAY[] and '{}'::int[] to create an array?

Tags: arrays, postgresql

What's the difference between using ARRAY[] and '{}'::int[] when it comes to performance? Is one of them better than the other?

I'm using functions which contains queries that use conditions like:

```
  AND ('{13,57,30,59}'::int[] && _user_profiles)
```

where is necessary to compare an array (`_user_profiles` in the example) against a static array (**'{13,57,30,59}'::int[]**).

This way to compare replies in almost every one of these queries. So what would be better to use?

1. `AND ('{13,57,30,59}'::int[] && _user_profiles)`

**(OR)**

2. `AND (ARRAY[13,57,30,59] && _user_profiles)`

Comment: Just try it `explain (analyze) select '{13,57,30,59}'::int[] from generate_series(1,10e6)` and `explain (analyze) select ARRAY[13,57,30,59]  from generate_series(1,10e6)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both forms are evaluated at parse time and the result is the same, so there shouldn't be any difference.

To see that for yourself, run both queries with `EXPLAIN (VERBOSE)` and check for differences in the execution plan.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Is your answer based on any documentation or is it based on your expertise?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of explanation. I have added a sentence recommending `EXPLAIN` to check the execution plan.

Comment: Also used the EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) suggested by @a_horse_with_no_name and got this result: https://imgur.com/a/ee3tYPu So I'll take them as the same in terms of performance.Thank you.